# percentile of a normal distribution nearer to which k,k+1,k-1 standard deviations above or below the mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

What process to use to determine whether the nth percentile of a normal distribution is closer to the k,k-1,or k+1 standard deviations above or below the mean?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "closer."  On the face of it, all you need to do is look at the numbers and compare them: there doesn't even seem to be a statistical question here.  Maybe you're trying to ask a different question than the one you have posed?

Comment: You can directly calculate - to as much accuracy as you're ever likely to care about (or look up via tables)  - how many standard deviations a given percentile is from the mean. e.g. the 70th percentile is 0.5244 standard deviations above the mean, the 12th percentile is 1.175 standard deviations below the mean and decide for yourself which integer you think is closer in either absolute distance or in difference in probability, or whatever criterion you like. I agree with whuber, it seems like you're seeking something other than what you asked. Please edit your question to add more context.